How to disable exceptions in boost recursive_directory_iterator?
I am using Ubuntu 20.04, c++ 11 and Boost Filesystem 1.71. Just trying to traverse directory that contains some elements not accessible by current user in c++ but exception always occurs when such items are encountered. I thought that by specifying error code it should not throw exception? This is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

void sometest(const fs::path &f) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    auto begin = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(f, ec);
    const auto end = fs::recursive_directory_iterator();
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->path().string() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int result = EXIT_FAILURE;
    try {
        sometest("/tmp");
        result = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}

Update:
Ok, I realized that by doing assingnment I invalidated the error object hence the throwing. Here is the updated code version
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

void sometest1(const fs::path &f) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    auto it = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(f, ec);
    auto end = fs::recursive_directory_iterator();
    for (; it != end; it.increment(ec))
    {
        std::cout << it->path().string() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int result = EXIT_FAILURE;
    try {
        sometest1("/tmp");
        result = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return result;
}


With this change it lists elements in directory until it reaches the one with permission issue and continues to print that one infinitely.
Update 2
Changing the function like this
void sometest1(const fs::path &f) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    auto it = fs::recursive_directory_iterator(f, ec);
    auto end = fs::recursive_directory_iterator();
    while ( it != end )
    {
        std::cout << it->path().string() << std::endl;
        it.increment(ec);
        if (ec.failed()) {
            std::cout << ec.message() << std::endl;
            if (it == end) {
                std::cout << "Ending" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}


Gives this output
/tmp/instantclient-basic-linuxx64.zip.1
/tmp/origdir
/tmp/mc-darko
/tmp/tmp.N3DqnDv5gf
/tmp/tmp.N3DqnDv5gf/ijent
/tmp/7E5SS5
/tmp/mc-root
Permission denied
Ending

So after error iterator becomes invalid and that can not be prevented.
Conclusion is that if one needs to use Boost Filesystem library V3 ( which is the one available from Boost 1.44+ and has no access to V4 which is available from 1.77+) we have to avoid using recursive_directory_iterator.

What's the thrown exception? The output is missing from your post.

Unfortunately Ubuntu 20.04 comes with Boost 1.71 and that one does not contain skip permission denied thing...

It seems to me that recursive iterator is useless when dealing with varying permissions. One has to use directory_iterator and check everything before diving in or write it's own recursive iterator...

Try replace ++it with it.increment(ec) and add logic for checking this error. See doc.

I did change but not sure what to do when error happens. It seems iterator just returns end then.

Some body recommended to use skip_permission_denied, but the comment is gone. With std::filesystem that would be the best option. I guess boost - as the reference implementation - must support it too.

@Red.Wave Indeed, the comment regarding skip_permission_denied was mine but was based on the OP's original post which mentioned Boost 1.76.0.  Unfortunately it's not available in 1.71.0 so I removed the comment.  However, it is available in >= 1.72.0 and looks like a fairly simple back-port.  Otherwise the solution is to simply install a newer version of Boost and/or upgrade the compiler/standard-library to bring in std::filesystem.

I need to use libraries as they are on the distro by default, so no upgrade available.

I give up, this is much easier to work with nftw
